# Why is SED echoing rather than editing: sed '/^;text1/!b;:a;n;//ba;i\text2'

Tags: string, bash, sed, centos, centos7

```
sed '/^;date.timezone =/!b;:a;n;//ba;i\date.timezone = Europe/London' /etc/php.ini
```

You can probably guess Im creating a script for setting up LAMP servers.

In the above example the text is not replaced but instead the changes are displayed on the console.

I my goal was to insert `date.timezone = Europe/London` the last occurence of `;date.timezone =`

Comment: You aren't using the `-i` flag to tell sed to modify in place.

Comment: OK, now i feel silly. That was it. Put that as the answer if you like?

Comment: Probably better to just close/delete the question. This comes up somewhat often and doesn't need another question about it.

Comment: You can delete the question. I would encourage you. This place looks weird

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Etan Reisner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/258523/etan-reisner):
You aren't using the -i flag to tell sed to modify in place.